# sending hex bytes to serial in bash

Tags: bash, command-line, serial-port, serial-communication

I am able to send hec bytes to a serial port using

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 speed 115200 cs8 -cstopb -parenb -echo
echo -en '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

But when I try to do this in a loop reading test from a file, it doesnt want to work

```
#!/bin/bash
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 speed 115200 cs8 -cstopb -parenb -echo
while read line
do
    name=$line
    echo -en $name | tr -d ' ' > /dev/ttyUSB0
    sleep 0.04
done < $1
```

I call the script like this

```
./sendData.sh file.txt
```

file.txt has some simple content like this

Try 1

```
\\ xFF\\ x00\\ x00\\ x00\\ x00\\ x00\\ x00\\ x00\\ x00\\ x00\\ x00\\ x00\\ x00\\ x00\\ x00\\ x00\\ x00\\ x00\\ x00\\ x00\\ x00\\ x00\\ x00\\ x00
```

Try 2

```
\xFF\xF2\x00\xFF\xF2\x00\xFF\xF2\x00\xFF\xF2\x00\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF
```

Could someone point to me what is missing.

Comment: `echo` is tricky, try `printf` or a dedicated hex conversion tool like `xxd` or `hexdump`.

Comment: @tripleee can you suggest any sample to try ?

Comment: `printf "%s\n" "$line"`? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter doesn't work :(

Comment: If you're getting error message, best to edit your question to include that information. Best to indicate how you will know it is working. This exhausts my knowledge (of which there is none) about communicating to a `/dev/USB*`. I won't be able to debug what is happening there. Good Luck!

Comment: @shellter read -r did the trick. thank you very much for your help though. There was no error btw.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `read` interprets escape sequences by default, effectively removing your backslashes. Make your file contain e.g. `\x01\x02\x03` and use `read -r`:

```
while read -r line
do
  echo -en "$line" > /dev/ttyUSB0
done < "$1"
```

Comment: It worked. Just a minor modification. I had to use echo -en $line (without quotes) Please edit it just in case someone bumps into it.

Comment: That should not be the case. Can you do `read -r line < "$1"; echo -en $line | od -t x1 -c; echo -en "$line" | od -t x1 -c;` and post the output?

Comment: Both give the same output. Its a bit long to type the output here. But, oddly the serial gets the correct out only without the quotes.

Comment: Sorry I just double checked. Both work! There was a typo in my code.